# better output formatting using json_encode

Tags: php, arrays, json, formatting

How to produce result like

```
"alpa":[{"a":"a"},{"b":"b"},{"c":"c"}]
```

so I can easily get them in JS.

My code currently is like this:

```
$arr = array();
$arr["a"] = $a;
$arr["b"] = $b;
$arr["c"] = $c;

echo json_encode($arr);
```

output

```
{"a":"a"},{"b":"b"},{"c":"c"}
```

Comment: change $arr to $arr['alpa']

Answer (score 1):

```
array(
    'alpa' => array(
        'a' => 'a',
        'b' => 'b',
        'c' => 'c',
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$arr = array();
$arr['alpa']["a"] = $a;
$arr['alpa']["b"] = $b;
$arr['alpa']["c"] = $c;
echo json_encode($arr);
```